# zend framework 2 - Cache config files

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

i'm trying to enable the cache for the config files in zend framework 2 :

the module.config.php ( part of services ) :

```
 'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
                 $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
                     $memcache = new \Memcache();
                     $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
                     $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
                 return $cache;
         },
        ),
    ),
```

the application.config.php ( part of enabling the cache for config ):

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,
        'config_cache_key' => md5('config'),
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
        'module_map_cache_key' => md5('module_map'),
        'cache_dir' => "./data/cache/modulecache",
    ),
```

And here the error i got :

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config files can't be cached if they contain anonymous functions (in your case, the value for  `doctrine.cache.mycache`). You will need to move just that part out of the config file and into your `Module.php` class' `getServiceConfig()` instead. That should fix the issue.

Comment: thanks for the relpy , i've merged that part in the Module.php but i don't know how to replace it in my module.config.php , can u calrify more the issu , thanks.

Comment: If you've moved it to Module.php, just remove that part from the config file. ZF merges the two together automatically.

Comment: for the part of doctrine it's ok thanks , i have an other issu is that i i got the closure for Adapter , i've serached a lot for it in module.config and in Module but can't find it , can u guide me here plz ?

Comment: I can't help you find something in your config file without being able to see the whole thing. Surely it shouldn't be too difficult to spot?